# Go routines with kafka consumer channel and context

Tags: go, channel

I have a simple kafka consumer for which  I have created a handle and trying to read it using a go routine:

```
func process(ctx context.Context){
consumer := queueHandle.Consume(topic_ops_req, consumerHandler)
// Get signal for finish
doneCh := make(chan struct{})
go func(consumer chan *sarama.ConsumerMessage, ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case msg, ok := <-consumer:
            if !ok {
                logger.Info("Channel has been closed")
                doneCh <- struct{}{}
                return
            }

            var request queue.Request
            err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Value, &request)
            if err != nil {
                logger.Error("consumer unmarshal err", err)
                panic(err)
            }
            res, err := new_process(ctx, request, service) // call another func
            if err != nil {
                //TODO
            }
            result = res
            doneCh <- struct{}{}

        case <-ctx.Done():
            logger.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Context ended  with err : %s", ctx.Err()))
            doneCh <- struct{}{}

        }
    }
}(consumer, ctx)
<-doneCh
```

}

The issue I am seeing is that once I introduce the "case <-ctx.Done()", the go routine does not enter the "case msg, ok := <-consumer" and always returns that the context ended. How do I my go func work with both consumer channel and ctx.Done() ?

Comment: do you have any timeouts higher in the hierarchy? It looks it's a timeout/cancellation issue.

Comment: My context deadline is very higher value. I also see the entry made to the topic from where i am trying to consume. If i comment out case ctx.Done(), I get the response immediately.